# string was not recognized as a valid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ola.
Este problema esta ocorrendo somente quando coloco o site no iis. Já tentei varias soluções, porém, não consigo resolver.Abaixo o trecho de código onde ocorre o problema:

```
public DataTable SelecionaConsulta(string dtaIni,string dtaFim)
{
  return consulta.SELECT_VISITA(Convert.ToDateTime(dtaIni).ToString("yyyyMMdd"), Convert.ToDateTime(dtaFim).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

}
```

Mesmo quando executo o sistema utilizando o visual studio do servidor de aplicações onde fica o iis não ocorre erros,só ocorre quando executo no iis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é porque a sua aplicação não define nenhuma cultura. Logo, a cultura usada será a que estiver definida no Windows.

Localmente isso vai funcionar porque seu Windows está configurado com uma cultura (provavelmente pt-*) e a data passada por parâmetro tem o formato usado nesta cultura. No servidor não vai funcionar porque a cultura é outra, então o formato de data **não será válido**.

Se você sabe os formatos de antemão e tem certeza que eles sempre serão iguais, pode usar um `ParseExact` para converter a `string` para `DateTime`.

É interessante você atentar para estes detalhes de cultura, talvez seja muito melhor cuidar isto do que usar o `ParseExact`, mas sem mais detalhes não tem como te ajudar muito.

```
public DataTable SelecionaConsulta(string dtaIni, string dtaFim)
{
     var formato = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
     DateTime dataInicio;
     var dtIniConvertida = DateTime.TryParseExact(dtaIni, formato, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dataInicio);

     DateTime dataFim;
     var dtFimConvertida = DateTime.TryParseExact(dtaFim, formato, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dataFim);

     if(!dtIniConvertida && !dtFimConvertida)
         //Algo deu errado em uma das conversões

     return consulta.SELECT_VISITA(dataInicio.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), dataFim.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
}
```